# My CSV data when read into R via read.table after so many lines, stops creating new rows and separating the values by ","

Tags: r, csv, import, read.table

When reading my CVS data into R, after reading so many values as normal the data stops being separated by "," leaving lots of data missing
Here is how I load my data into R.

```
CODATA <- read.table( file.choose("CO2 Emissions per country.cvs"), header = TRUE, sep = "," )
```

I'm given this warning.

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 1 did not have 3 elements
Warning messages:
1: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  EOF within quoted string
2: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  number of items read is not a multiple of the number of columns
```

Then the value is...

```
"Cote dIvoire,0.42,0.44,0.44,0.43,0.45,0.49,0.46,0.51,0.45,0.4,0.33,0.32,0.38,0.33,0.29,0.28,0.26,0.25,0.23,0.21,0.21,0.2,0.21,0.21,0.22,0.25,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.37,0.36,0.36,0.29,0.31,0.32,0.32,0.3,0.34,0.31,0.29\nNigeria,0.1,0.12,0.15,0.16,0.18,0.22,0.27,0.3,0.32,0.35,0.39,0.42,0.41,0.37,0.38,0.35,0.35,0.36,0.36,0.3,0.34,0.4,0.36,0.29,0.28,0.3,0.34,0.29,0.31,0.34,0.38,0.39,0.36,0.36,0.4,0.35,0.32,0.33,0.27,0.29\nKenya,0.28,0.28.....(and so on)
```

where the values haven't been separated. The data is meant to start a new line with each country. It reads the previous 100 or so countries as normal up to Cote dIvoire.

Is there any way to fix without editing the csv file and changing the code to load it in?
Thank you for any help given.

Answer (score 0):

You're best checking over the CSV file again for any problems. You could also try CODATA <- read.csv("CO2 Emissions per country.csv") rather than read.table?